# Word search generator

Tags: c#, arrays, char, puzzle, wordsearch

I'm writing a Word search puzzle in c# and I'm almost done, only missing one thing. 
I have a char[,] matrix that I fill up with words I read from a txt file, and if there's no available places for a word left, I fill up the remaining spots with random letters. My problem is that I don't know how to make words that contains the some letter cross eachother. Here's my code for the word placing:

```
    private bool PlaceWord(string word, int _row, int _col, int x, int y)
    {
        if(x > 0)
        {
            if (_row + word.Length > row)
                return false;
        }
        if(x < 0)
        {
            if (_row - word.Length < 0)
                return false;
        }
        if(y > 0)
        {
            if (_col + word.Length > col)
                return false;
        }
        if(y < 0)
        {
            if (_col - word.Length < 0)
                return false;
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < word.Length; i++)
        {
            if (matrix[(i * x) + _row, (i * y) + _col] != ' ')
                return false;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < word.Length; i++)
        {
            matrix[(i * x) + _row, (i * y) + _col] = word[i];
            answers[(i * x) + _row, (i * y) + _col] = word[i];
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your first for-loop

```
if ((matrix[i*x+_row, i*y+_col] != ' ') && (matrix[i*x+_row, i*y+_col] != word[i]))
  return false
```

Comment: I'm only going by the code you have presented, which seems to return `false` if the word does not fit in the location and direction requested. In what way should it work?

Comment: I want it to cross a word when it tries to place a new word. For example:
        `P A L E`
        `# # O #`
        `# # V #`
        `# # E #`
Now it works like this:
        `P A L E`
        `# # # #`
        `L O V E`
        `# # # #`
It just places the new word to an available empty space, and fills the rest (#) with random letters.

Comment: Then you need to implement an algorithm which searches for available locations and distinguishes between ones which do or don't cross other words. You could use what you have as a starting point, which detects non-crossing locations. I believe my suggestion also detects crossing locations. Test all possible locations and select one...